# Windows Server Shared Folder Audit

Tags: windows

I have been asked to Audit one Folder which is in the File Server. 
Audit means

- how may user are accessing that Folder
- any changes
- Edit
- New
- Delete Files and Folder

need to be recorded.

I know this can be done using Local GP in Audit Policy, but want to know how the *security events log* can be filtered only for this particular Folder.

I also want to know if any third party software can be used for pulling a report about what has happened in this folder.

Answer (score 3):

Example of a custom event viewer filter to display events for folder C:\TEST:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[EventData[Data[@Name="ObjectName"] = "C:\TEST"]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

You can also perform similar custom filtering with Get-WinEvent for extracting the data.